# Force assign a drive letter to a USB flash disk

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I have an SQLCE database which is stored my pen drive. Whenever I plug my pen drive into my computer I would like it to always mount to `Y:`. The reason for choosing `Y:` is because it is unlikely that the computers I work with will have any other device mounted to `Y:`.

Is there any way to force my computer to mount my pen drive to `Y:`?

Answer (score 3):

You can manually assign your pen-drive to Y: using the steps below:

- Right Click on Computer.
- Select Manage.
- Select Disk Management (make sure your pen-drive is plugged in so you can see it in the right-hand pane).
- Right Click your pen-drive.
- Click Change Drive Letter and Paths.
- On the popup, click the existing letter and click Change.
- On the next popup, select the drive letter `Y` and press OK.
- Press `YES` on the warning window, and you are done.

Comment: I did same above but it is not working all the machine so have to do for all the machine..thank you..

Comment: It is per machine, yes.

Comment: @JitendraJadav: Drive letter assignment is not stored on the drive itself, it is an OS function.